# Trying to improve my backup GUI in Python

Tags: python, file, user-interface, new-operator

I'm trying to make a program to help me backup in one click, i've been on youtube and site trying to understand how to write this and so far it ok. my code is super sample and i just wanted to know if anyone can help me with this, so far im using five script. here is the first main thing

```
 from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


class FileBackup:

    def tbf(self):
        import sa
        vars(sa.py)
        from sa import files
        print(files)
        self.printtext.insert(0.0, str(files) + "............................Done")

    def tbf2(self):
        import sa1
        vars(sa1.py)
        from sa1 import files
        print(files)
        self.printtext.insert(0.0, str(files) + "............................Done")

    def tbf3(self):
        import sa2
        vars(sa2.py)
        from sa2 import files
        print(files)
        self.printtext.insert(0.0, str(files) + "............................Done")

    def tbf4(self):
        import sa3
        vars(sa3.py)
        from sa3 import files
        print(files)
        self.printtext.insert(0.0, str(files) + "............................Done")

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="BackUp Fl Studio Data Folder", command=self.tbf)
        self.printButton.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="BackUp Music Folder", command=self.tbf2)
        self.printButton.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="BackUp FL Studio Projects", command=self.tbf3)
        self.printButton.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="BackUp ProTools", command=self.tbf4)
        self.printButton.pack()

        self.quitbutton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitbutton.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.printtext = Text(frame, wrap=WORD,)
        self.printtext.pack(side=BOTTOM)


b = FileBackup(root)

Tk.mainloop(root)
```

the next script i have is:

```
import os
import shutil

MAIN = r'Z:\HardDrives\Aaron HardDrive\protools'
DIRS = r'D:\pro tool files'


for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(DIRS):
        print('root', root)
        print('subdirs', subdirs)
        print('files', files)
        for file in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            shutil.copy(path, MAIN)



def py():
    return None
```

the sa,sa1,sa2,sa3,sa4 is just a copy of the second script with different paths

So what i need is just to clean it up and make it better. My goal for this is to fix it for all my computer to make it super easy to backup my files. I will be slow at this cause im super new, But im willing to try new thing to help.

***My Goals:***

1. Keep it simple
2. Copy folder over too
3. Display the copying process and when it done
4. Have the gui not freeze when copying
5. Put a Entry field to change the path at anytime
6. Clean it all up

---

### Your Help

---

- Any links to forms that would help, even if it a small thing like
  placement, tricks, or looks on the gui
- Any video on youtube that explain things
- Last just addon or Write python for me to help me

---

Thank You,

*spriteurboi*